# Competitions/datasets fit for exploring Pearl's graphical causal models

Tags: references, causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

**Are there any competitions/challenges/datasets fit for testing Pearl's graphical causal inference methods?** I do not necessarily mean live competitions.

I would expect these setups to be different than any other ordinary dataset found in Kaggle, as we should be expecting the following components to be part of the setup -

- A fully/partly specified causal model (DAG) of the system.
- Ground truth or target variable values for different interventions to measure the causal model's performance.
- Ground truth/target variable values for counterfactuals. This is optional.

My aim is to test out majorly the inferential capabilities; challenges around causal discovery I want to avoid for now (however, if someone wants to cite such resources please feel free to). Hence the necessity of the DAG being specified, at least partially.

It would be better if I can find examples both for non-time-series and time-series scenarios. This is because time-series datasets might be a bit more difficult to handle than non-time-series ones.